# Цикличное создание таблиц в JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

У меня есть объект json.

```
{
    "_id": "5f0f3919e9df2fb4d87d2320",
    "name": "Hello",
    "ru": "Привет",
    "en": "Hello",
    "es": "Hola",
    "theme": "Приветствие",
    "__v": 0
}
```

В дальнейшем, это будет большой массив из повторяющихся по структуре элементов. (ключи _id, name, ru, en, es, theme, __v будут везде)

Мне нужно,, чтобы посредством цикла for или же $each создавались таблицы по типу:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Ru</td>
                <td>En</td>
                <td>Es</td>
                <td>Theme</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Hello</td>
                <td>Привет</td>
                <td>Hello</td>
                <td>Hola</td>
                <td>Приветствие</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Подскажите, возможно ли это как-то реализовать на чистом js или jquery?

UPD: Код после ответа @Инквизитор :

```js
const requestURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", requestURL);
request.responseType = "json";
request.send();

request.onload = function() {
    const dataDB = request.response;
    tableCycle(dataDB);
    console.log(dataDB);
    console.log(tableCycle(dataDB));
    console.log(dataDB[0]["name"]);
};

function tableCycle(jsonObj) {
    let output = "";
    for(i = 0; i < jsonObj.lenght; i++) {
        output +="<tr><td>";
        output += jsonObj[i]["name"];
        output += "</td><td>"
        output += jsonObj[i]["ru"];
        output += "</td><td>"
        output += jsonObj[i]["en"];
        output += "</td><td>"
        output += jsonObj[i]["es"];
        output += "</td><td>"
        output += jsonObj[i]["theme"];
        output += "</td></tr>"
    }
    document.write(output);
}
```

Comment: В jquery есть функции создания html, расширения DOM. В js есть циклы по массивавм. В чем проблема? Где ваша реализация? Где описание ошибок?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как реализовать **цикличное** создание таблиц. В методах, которые я искал в гугле описывался только вариант с уже имеющимся в html теге table с атрибутом id, как [здесь](https://qna.habr.com/q/581231). Меня интересует как встраивать в body тег теги table, tr, td и наполнять их циклом.

Comment: Добавить html  в документ: `$('body').append('<table></table>');`. Затем в цикле добавляете к созданной таблице строки `array.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {$('body > table').append('<tr><td>' + item[attr1] + '</td><td>' + item[attr2] + '</td></tr>')});`

Comment: а где начало таблицы `output = '<table>'` и конец `output += '</table>'`?

Comment: Смотрите первый кусок кода - сперва добавляете пустой тег `'<table></table>'` в `body`, затем в цикле наполняете его строками с данными

Comment: вместо `document.write(output);` правильнее было бы `document.body.innerHTML += output;`

Comment: @cauf , мне необходима генерация ***таблиц***. Мне нужна не одна, а несколько. Одна таблица - один шаблон с ключами.

Comment: @Shift я в ответе добавил пример - делаете подобным образом для каждого набора данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть у нас есть некоторый массив данных. Нужно создать и наполнить таблицу

```js
// пример данных
var data = [
  {value: "one", char: "A", literal: "a"},
  {value: "two", char: "B", literal: "b"},
  {value: "three", char: "C", literal: "c"}
];

// добавим саму таблицу на страницу
$('body').append('<table></table>'); 

// добавим шапку
$('body > table').append(
    '<tr><th>№</th><th>Номер</th><th>Буква</th><th>Символ</th></tr>'
  );

// пройдем уиклом по всем элементам массива и сгенерируем строки таблицы
data.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
  $('body > table').append(
    '<tr><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td>' + item.value + '</td><td>' + item.char + '</td><td>'  + item.literal + '</td></tr>'
  );
});
```

```css
table, td, th {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p>Здесь будет таблица:</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Именно то, что я искал. Хотелось бы спросить: Можно ли вашу длинную строку разбить на несколько посредством использования метода append() несколько раз?

Comment: Можно, но чем больше будет `append` тем хуже оптимизация. В вашем случае возможно некритично.

Answer (score 1):

Легче легкого. Развейте дальше сами:

Массив с данными:

```
var phrases = [{
"_id": "5f0f3919e9df2fb4d87d2320",
"name": "Hello",
"ru": "Привет",
"en": "Hello",
"es": "Hola",
"theme": "Приветствие",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "5f0f3919e9df2fb4d87d2321",
"name": "Good bye",
"ru": "Пока",
"en": "Good bye",
"es": "Vali davaj",
"theme": "Прощание",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "5f0f3919e9df2fb4d87d2322",
"name": "Hate",
"ru": "Шоб вы так жили",
"en": "Hate",
"es": "$%#*!",
"theme": "Ненависть",
"__v": 0
}
]
```

Функция, генерирующая строки таблицы:

```
function drawTableEntries(topics) {
  var temp = "";
  for (i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
  temp += "<tr><td>" + phrases[i].name + "<\/td><td>" + phrases[i].ru + "<\/td><td>" + phrases[i].en + "<\/td><td>" + phrases[i].es + "<\/td><td>" + phrases[i].theme + "<\/td><\/tr>";
  }
  document.write(temp);
}
```

Comment: Не работает. Возможно, я с чем-то напортачил. Сейчас добавлю в ответ полный код файла script.js